# How to get the ID of rowSpan TD

Tags: javascript, html-table

```
<table id="foo" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" class="date">Monday</td>
    <td>Cell A1 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A2 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A3 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" class="date">Tuesday</td>
    <td>Cell B1 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell B2 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell B3 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On the above table, how can I get the value of rowSpan of the parent TD? For example, if I click on the edit link of cell A3, a Javascript function will be called. In that function, I need the rowSpan value of the parent TD (i.e. Monday).

These  and  are dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery try this one:

```
$("#foo").on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'), 
        rowspan = 0,
        text, td;

    while(tr.length && !rowspan ) {
        td = tr.find('td:first');
        rowspan = td.attr('rowspan');
        tr = tr.prev();            
    }

    alert(td.text());
})
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bJfKL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your function `this` is a reference to the  `a` element, you could do this:

```
var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;

tr = tr.parentNode.rows[tr.rowIndex - (tr.rowIndex % 3)];

alert(tr.cells[0].innerHTML);
```

---

Or if it's not guaranteed to be every 3 rows, you can traverse and test the `rowSpan`.

```
var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;

while (tr && tr.cells[0].rowSpan === 1)
    tr = tr.parentNode.rows[tr.rowIndex - 1];

alert(tr.cells[0].innerHTML);
```

---

FWIW, you should probably take advantage of multiple `<tbody>` elements. This makes things much simpler.

```
<table id="foo" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td rowspan="3" class="date">Monday</td> 
            <td>Cell A1 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Cell A2 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Cell A3 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td rowspan="3" class="date">Tuesday</td> 
            <td>Cell B1 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Cell B2 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Cell B3 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then its just:

```
var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0];

tr.cells[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: You're right. I changed it to `tr.cells[0].innerHTML`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: It continues the traversal while `rowSpan` is `1`, which is the default. So it will halt when it finds one that is longer `1`. I now see there's trouble in that I'm iterating text nodes too, so the loop will halt early.